# Ist "Arbeiten in die Tourismusbranche" korrekt?

Tags: dative, subject

Ist "Arbeiten in die Tourismusbranche" korrekt? There is no subject on this sentence, so we could not say "Arbeiten in der Tourismusbranche" because there is not a reference to make an indirect complement. If it's Dative, I would like to know where is the linguistic explanation.

Comment: Der Kontext fehlt. Ist das eine Überschrift?

Comment: You're confused. A certain type of German object uses the dative, **but not every dative appears as an object**. In particular, prepositions also govern specific cases, and this has nothing to to with verb-argument structure - it holds even in a sentence fragment like this.

Answer (score 7):

Es spielt keine Rolle, ob es ein Subjekt gibt oder nicht.
Es spielt auch keine Rolle, ob es ein Verb gibt oder nicht.
Es kommt nur darauf an,
ob "in" mit einer Richtungsangabe (*) gebraucht wird
(dann steht der Akkusativ),
oder nicht
(dann steht der Dativ).
Das gilt selbst dann, wenn gar kein Beziehungswort vorhanden ist,
zum Beispiel in Überschriften oder bei Zeitangaben:
"Im Juni 2019", "Im Urlaub", "In der Natur",
"In guten und in schlechten Zeiten",
"Europa im Mittelalter", "Jobs im Handwerk"
(alle mit Dativ).

(*) Auch wenn "in" temporal gebraucht wird, *kann* es sich manchmal um eine Richtungsangabe handeln. Zum Beispiel steht bei "Tanz in den Mai" der Akkusativ, da es sich um eine Veranstaltung vom 30. April bis zum 1. Mai handelt. Meist steht bei Zeitangeben aber "in" mit Dativ.

Answer (score 5):

Forget about direct vs. indirect objects (or complements, as you put it) because they don't match accusative vs. dative objects. They do it four out of five times and that fifth time they don't will drive you nuts. Forget about this concept. It does not help you in German.

But this isn't the problem you face with this snippet in either case.

---

What this snippet is about is an adverbial featuring one of the nine **dual-way-prepositions** *an, auf, hinter, **in**, neben, über, unter, vor, zwischen*. These prepositions

- require the accusative when a direction is meant.
- require the dative when a place is meant.

IMPORTANT: this rule only applies to these nine prepositions. Other prepositions may require the accusative and mean a place or require the dative and mean a direction, or even require the genitive. Some change the case depending on whether they are used as a preposition or postposition. As always in German, it's quite a mess.

> <s>Arbeiten in die Tourismusbranche</s>

*Die Tourismusbranche* is put in accusative in your example. It's the preposition *in*, so this is a direction.

**What should that even mean?**

You are talking about working at a place, not in some direction. So it must be

> Arbeiten in der Tourismusbranche

---

You could of course use *arbeiten* with a direction in another context, e.g.

> Der Bohrer arbeitet sich in die Wand.